# ssh-agent – What does this process do?

Tags: ssh

I've found something odd in my system monitor. In my process list was 'ssh-agent', now I'm not too familiar with SSH but I know that it can't be normal for an SSH service to be running on a VANILLA desktop Ubuntu installation. I've ran rkhunter and it came back with nothing in particular.

I ran this command and here are the results:

```
trev@trev-pc:~$ ps -aux | grep ssh
trev     1635  0.0  0.0  11140    48 ?        Ss   Feb18   0:00 /usr/bin/ssh-agent /usr/bin/dbus-launch --exit-with-session /usr/bin/im-launch mate-session
trev    15992  0.0  0.0  15192  2144 pts/1    S+   20:06   0:00 grep --color=auto ssh
```

What's going on here? Is this something to be concerned about?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, this is not something to be concerned about. This is `ssh-agent`, not `sshd`, which is the SSH daemon. If you have a look at [`man ssh-agent`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/ssh-agent.1.html):

```
 ssh-agent is a program to hold private keys used for public key
 authentication (RSA, DSA, ECDSA, ED25519).  The idea is that ssh-agent is
 started in the beginning of an X-session or a login session, and all
 other windows or programs are started as clients to the ssh-agent
 program.
```

The way it works is that when you use SSH to connect to somewhere (the command-line client `ssh` is installed by default, and other programs, like the file browser can also act as SSH clients), the connecting program will use the agent instead of loading the private key itself:

```
 The agent will never send a private key over its request channel.
 Instead, operations that require a private key will be performed by the
 agent, and the result will be returned to the requester.  This way,
 private keys are not exposed to clients using the agent.
```

The benefits are that you only need to unlock the private key once per session (the agent will then store it in memory), and clients *never* see your unencrypted private key directly.

It's the *opposite* of a backdoor, in a way.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not very good with this kind of stuff! I appreciate the well written reply.

Comment: What prevents someone from spoofing the result that the keys match?

Comment: @LiamClink The mathematics behind public key authentication essentially mean that computing a matching result is practically impossible without the private key (depending on key sizes, etc.).

Comment: That means that the "matched" result isn't just a true/false, how then is it determined whether the keys match in a way that prevents spoofing?

Comment: @Liam https://security.stackexchange.com/a/23243/54387, https://ssd.eff.org/en/module/deep-dive-end-end-encryption-how-do-public-key-encryption-systems-work#3