# Lost passphrase for kde plasma

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, kde, passphrase

Is any way to recover a forgotten ssh passphrase which I do not recall ever needing to input in gnome but KDE asks for the passphrase at each new session. Is my only solution to uninstall KDE and then reinstall?

I am running version 20.04

Comment: You can totally recover it! Do [these steps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password) work for you?

Comment: There is a [difference between ssh passphrase for authentication keys and Ubuntu password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019999/key-based-ssh-login-that-requires-both-key-and-password/1020093#1020093). Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1397117/edit) ans clarify whether you forgot your **ssh key authentication passphrase** or your Ubuntu password?

Comment: Hello and thanks for your response. What I am referring to is a forgotten ssh passphrase which makes my kde plasma session difficult to use. That is why I was wondering if there is no other option to hack the passphrase should I do a complete uninstall of KDE and then install anew?