# How to enforce 2FA while already enforcing public key authentication?

Tags: openssh

I have been using google 2FA for a while and it works solid.
How can I enforce 2AF for some users in addition to ssh key based login?
All websites I visited explain how to set it up, but the result is it finally does not require 2FA if ssh keys are used.

I am aiming for this:

userA: This account is nonprivileged. It has ssh key authentication enabled. Passwordless login is working, no 2FA token is required.

userB: The account has admin privilege (e.g. sudo). ssh keys auth is enabled. I want this user to also use the 2FA token as a mandatory 2nd method for additional security.

Comment: I don't know about 2FA, but you can use key **and** password. You can also use a pass phrase with your private key.

Comment: See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019999/key-based-ssh-login-that-requires-both-key-and-password/1020093#1020093) for an alternate solution that requires birth keys and a password.