# Enable ssh login with password for a user

Tags: server, permissions, ssh, login, password

I am the admin of a Ubuntu 20.04 server and I want to enable `ssh` login for a user through password, rather than using key pairs.

The `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file on the host looks like this (`<username>` is replaced by its actual username):

```
Host*
    SendEnv LANG LC_*
    HashKnownHosts yes
    GSSAPIAuthentication yes

Match User <username>
    PubkeyAuthentication no
    PreferredAuthentications password
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Still, when he tries to login as:

```
ssh \<username>@\<host>
```

he receive an error:

```
Permission denied (publickey)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK the ssh_config file is for configuring the host's ssh *clients* - it's the `sshd_config` file that controls the server's permitted authentication methods.

Comment: Wow, I am so dumb. It is working now. Cannot believe the amount of time I lost by editing the wrong file... Thank you very much!

Comment: @steeldriver, you should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Note: You have to edit the ssh daemon config, not the `ssh.config` in the remote computer.

I assume the ssh-server is configured to user key based authentication only and password based authentication is turned off in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`.

## Create an additional config file:

Newer versions of openssh-server allows creation of `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/*.conf` files rather than editing the ``/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file.

Create a new file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/10-password-login-for-special-user.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/10-password-login-for-special-user.conf
```

Add the following lines:

```
Match User <username>
    PasswordAuthentication yes
```

Replace `<username>` with the username of the special user.

Save the file using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> followed by <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then exit the editor by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>.

Restart the ssh service by the following command:

```
sudo systemctl restart ssh.service
```

Now the special user will be able to login remotely using password, while all other users will continue to use key based authentication.

Referrences:

- [SSH Allow Password For One User, Rest Only Allow Public Keys](https://serverfault.com/questions/307407/ssh-allow-password-for-one-user-rest-only-allow-public-keys)
- [Key based SSH login that requires both key AND password](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1019999/key-based-ssh-login-that-requires-both-key-and-password)

Hope this helps

Comment: Please note, that newer versions of `sshd` will be sensitive about the order of commands. If you want to place a `PasswordAuthentication no` in the configuration as well, make sure to put it below the `yes`, i.e. `Match User <username> ↲ PasswordAuthentication yes ↲ Match All ↲ PasswordAuthentication no`.